# Solving a system of equations where two variables can only be one of several discrete values

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve a three-equation system, but I need to constrain two of the variables so that they can only take one of several discrete values that I would specify (this is a circuit design problem where I need to find a resistor that can have a continuous range of values and two standard capacitors).  I attempted to use Solve[] using the logical OR operator || to constrain the two variables, but Mathematica tells me that the system is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities.  Does anybody know of a solution to this?

Here's the code:

```
Solve[{
  (10*^3 == 1/(2*Pi*Sqrt[10000*r2*c1*c2])),
  (20 == 3*Sqrt [r2*c2]/Sqrt[10000*c1]),
  (3 == Sqrt[r2/10000]*Sqrt [c1*c2]/(c1 + c2)),
  (r2 > 5000),
  (c1 == (10*^-12) || (100*^-12) || (22*^-12) || (0.001*^-6) || \
    (0.01*^-6) || (0.1*^-6)),
  (c2 == (10*^-12) || (100*^-12) || (22*^-12) || (0.001*^-6) || \
    (0.01*^-6) || (0.1*^-6))},
 {r2, c1, c2}]
```

Comment: `x == (1 || 2)` doesn't make sense (within Mathematica) but `(x == 1) || (x == 2)` does.  You can omit the parentheses from the latter.  If you use only exact numbers (i.e. there's no decimal point in them), then `Reduce` should theoretically work, but it's taking a very long time on my machine.

Comment: The problem is that you have three equations, but for any particular choice of `c1` and `c2`, you only have one variable to solve for: `r2`.  Do you have any reason to believe that *all three* equations will be satisfied for some value of `r2`?  The system looks overdetermined.

Comment: If you specify that Reduce should solve for Reals (as I suspect it is what you expect), the result is False. I guess it means that the system is unsolvable. (With the constraints provided, that is)

Answer (score 3):

This system of equations is overdetermined:

```
In[27]:= Solve[(10*^3 == 1/(2*Pi*Sqrt[10000*r2*c1*c2])) && (20 == 
    3*Sqrt[r2*c2]/Sqrt[10000*c1]) && (3 == 
    Sqrt[r2/10000]*Sqrt[c1*c2]/(c1 + c2)), {c1, c2, r2}, Reals]

Out[27]= {{c1 -> 3/(4000000000 π), c2 -> 11/(12000000000 π), r2 -> 4000000/11}}
```

Just using the first three equations you get a single solution.  This solution doesn't match any of your additional constraints for the values of `c1` and `c2`.  Thus there's no solution that satisfies this complete set of equations.

---

That said, generally the correct syntax to specify a discrete set of values would be

```
x == 1 || x == 2
```

and not

```
x == (1 || 2)  (* wrong *)
```